# get 400 response httpurlconnection sends post request

Tags: java, json, httprequest, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

Try to convert python code to java code for httppost request, but always get 400 response. try the same code with some local web services in my computer, there is no any issue. Please see the python code:

```
post_data = {'monitoredObjects':'VZLab-IViewG10-2','monitoredObjectType':'Probe'}

print(post_data)

postfields = urlencode(post_data)


response = BytesIO()

b = pycurl.Curl()

b.setopt(b.URL, base+"capture")

b.setopt(b.HTTPHEADER, ['username:'+username,'securitytoken:'+securitytoken])

b.setopt(b.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)

b.setopt(a.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)

b.setopt(b.WRITEDATA, response)

b.setopt(b.POST, 1)

b.setopt(b.POSTFIELDS, postfields)

b.perform()

b.close()
```

My java code:

```
public void method(){
    String securityToken = "12134";
    HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();

    header.put("username", username);
    header.put("password", password);
    header.put("securitytoken", securityToken);

    String api = "capture";

    JsonObject parameters = new JsonObject();

    parameters.addProperty("monitoredObjects", System.getProperty("monitoredObjects"));

    parameters.addProperty("monitoredObjectType", System.getProperty("monitoredObjectType"));
    String captureResult = executePost(baseUrl, api, header, parameters.toString(), "POST");

    String captureid = Xml.getXPathValue(result, "//startCapture/isa:captureId/text()");
}

public static String executePost(String baseUrl, String api, HashMap header, String urlParameters, String httpMethod) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl + api);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setRequestProperty("username", (String) header.get("username"));
        connection.setRequestProperty("securitytoken", (String) header.get("securitytoken"));

        /*
         * String userPassword = username + ":" + password; String encoding = new
         * sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes()); connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
         * encoding);
         */

        // connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        if (urlParameters != null) {
            String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(urlParameters);
            OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(encodedString);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            wr.close();

            // wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            // wr.close();
        }
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        logger.info("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        logger.info("Post headers : " + header);
        logger.info("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        // Get Response
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();

            logger.info("*** BEGIN ***");
            logger.info(response.toString());
            logger.info("*** END ***");
            return response.toString();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 400 HTTP response is about bad request, so you could have an error in your request structure, then could you put more information please, for example, what is the value of "baseUrl"? If you can't put that information, you can show its structure at least please.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you used a Json object on python for your request parameters and used `urlencode` to convert that Json Object in well formed url parameters. The `urlencode` requires that Json Object as parameter, but this is differente for Java.

The `URLEncoder.encode` method requires a String object as parameter, then you don't need to create a Json object on your Java code, you should do something like this:

```
...
String parameters = "monitoredObjects=VZLab-IViewG10-2&monitoredObjectType=Probe";
URLEncoder.encode(parameters);
...
```

Now, I know you converted the Json Object to String Object (`parameters.toString()`), but it just did something like this:

```
"{monitoredObjects:VZLab-IViewG10-2,monitoredObjectType:Probe}"
```

So it isn't a well formed url, for this reason you get a 400 HTTP reponse.

I share you documentation of the URLEncoder class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: String parameters = "monitoredObjects=VZLab-IViewG10-2&monitoredObjectType=Probe";
 It works in this way. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, if you like my answer, could you approve it, please?